# Declaring service name in providers when we are passing the same as a parameter to constructor

Tags: angular

Why should we declare a service name in providers when we are passing it as a parameter to component constructor

```
import {xComponent} from './x'
@Component({
providers : [xComponent]
})
export class xyz{
constructor(public x : xComponent){}
}
```

From the above, why should we declare the xComponent in providers if we are passing the same in constructor. Isn't that redundency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because providing and injecting are two different things.

Providing specifies where and how an instance of a service is created and what it's scope is.

Injecting is to specify a constructor parameter, where a service (or other injectable) instance needs to be passed in.

Comment: If I understand this correct .. if u declare the service in provider, angular creates a new instance there and injects to constructor... If not it goes up the hierarchy and get an instance from there and injects to constructor. ??

Comment: This answer :) I was gonna link this: https://angular.io/guide/architecture#dependency-injection, which goes well with your answer as with in link DI *very* shortly explained :)

Comment: @praveen exactly

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `providers`? Is it `@Component` providers or is it `@NgModule` providers?

If `@Component`, then it is not required anymore, if you use `@Inject` annotation on constructor parameters (I'm pretty sure it was required in beta, but soonish after release it was removed). However, it is still possible to use that approach for few special cases (e.g. if you need dynamic dependency, so you can get local instance of `Injector`, that contains services/classes listed in `providers`, but that is definitely not your case. Or you can list all Services that needs to be provided and remove `@Inject` annotation). But you still can find tons of outdated examples across internet.

If `@NgModule` - it is still required - that is entry point for `Injector` to get list of Classes available for DI. If you do not provide your service here, DI cannot be resolved in constructor via `@Inject`

Comment: Beta (except the last just before release) didn't have modules, therefore all providers were in `@Component()` or `@Directive()`. Now providers can be registered for modules and directives, and it defines the scope of instances created by providers.

Comment: If I don't want my service class to be available to entire app, I shouldn't declare in NgModule, I should do that in individual component. I'm asking about that case

Comment: Thank you @GünterZöchbauer.

Comment: @praveen - then update your question with code examples and proper issue description, rather than forcing community to guess what is your problem